# What is the difference between mat and matND?

Tags: python, opencv

I am trying to extract data from a binary mask. All goes well but changing to python will cause the data to shift a few pixels. It is enough so I cannot find the center. However saving the image will oldly enough display the pixels at the correct location

Here is my code. I basically create a normal mat to use as output. However a matnd is outputed according to the docs

Am I extracting the data properly? If so tell me. I am trying to find the center given points along the center. I kidda dont want my data to be shifted.

```
import cv2.cv as cv

def main():

   imgColor = cv.LoadImage(OPTICIMAGE, cv.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR)
   center, radius = centerandradus(imgColor)

def centerandradus(cvImg, ColorLower=None,ColorUpper=None):
   lowerBound = cv.Scalar(130, 0, 130);
   upperBound = cv.Scalar(171, 80, 171);
   size =  cv.GetSize(cvImg)

   output = cv.CreateMat(size[0],size[1],cv.CV_8UC1)
   cv.InRangeS(cvImg, lowerBound, upperBound,output)
   mask = np.asarray( output[:,:] )
   x,y = np.nonzero(mask)
   x, y = np.array(x),np.array(y)
   h,k  =  centerEstimate(x,y)
   return np.array([h,k]), radius

def centerEstimate(xList,yList):
   x_m = np.mean( np.r_[xList])
   y_m = np.mean( np.r_[yList])
   return x_m, y_m
```

Edit: I think it the problem with matND, since i notice the data is already shifted when I try to print out the data. If you need any more information please ask

Thank You for your time

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems there is no more differences between Mat and MatND. MatND is now obsolete.

By looking at opencv2/core.hpp (version 2.4.8):

```
typedef Mat MatND;
```

Answer (score 2):

I learn that the orientation of the data is different when I use findcontours or this matrix.

This matrix use height X width, while the contour put is as width X height. I hate reading apis.