# Possible to calculate 3d histogram from HSV and is it valuable?

Tags: c++, opencv

Is it possible to calculate a 3d histogram? Ie, so I can create a histogram from a HSV image where it captures the hue, saturation and value? And if it is possible, is there any benefit of a 3d histogram over a 2d one? Will it make detecting objects (using calcHist()) more accurate or faster?

I know how to create a 2d histogram but would it work for 3d aswell?

```
int h_bins = 50; int s_bins = 60;
int histSize[] = { h_bins, s_bins };

// hue varies from 0 to 179, saturation from 0 to 255
float h_ranges[] = { 0, 180 };
float s_ranges[] = { 0, 256 };

const float* ranges[] = { h_ranges, s_ranges };

// Use the o-th and 1-st channels
int channels[] = { 0, 1 };

calcHist(&hsv, 1, channels, Mat(), hist, 2, histSize, ranges, true, false);
```

Comment: There's no problem with creating an histogram for 3-channel images. Just make sure your `hist` is a `MatND`. The maximum dimension for the histogram is set by `CV_MAX_DIM` which is 32.

Comment: @Sunreef [a `Mat` is ok, no need for `MatND`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26522006/5008845)

Comment: @Miki Didn't know that, thanks for the info. I've always used `Mat` for images and `MatND` for histograms without thinking about it too much.

Comment: @Miki and Sunreef but would a SparseMat be advised for efficiency?

Comment: Probably not. For efficiency you can compute the 1D histogram for each channel separately, and then concatenate them in a _larger_ 1D histogram. Works quite good in practice, and you avoid to work with 3D matrices. Be carefull that H in hsv space is wrapped at 0 / 180, so you should take care of that when comparing histograms. My first approach would be to concatenate the 1D  B,G,R histograms a little quantized, and use histogram intersection. Then you can find out if you need HSV over BGR, or a better comparison metric

Comment: @JakeM If you have a third dimension with 60 bins, you will end up with a total of 180K bins in your histogram. If you take images with a small size (~600 * 400) that means already 240K pixels so chances are that most cases will contain something. If you take bigger images (~1920 * 1080), that's around 2M pixels. You have strong chances that almost all bins will contain values.
I wouldn't use a sparse matrix in this case since it will be full anyway.